# Execute code based on result of two parallel completable futures

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a scenario where in I have to issue two REST calls that return a value each based on the current system state, and based on those two values, have to trigger a final clean up task asynchronously - the flow of control being more like a 'Y' scenario . I have looked through the CompletableFuture interface, and is unable to find a way to accomplish this in a non-blocking fashion

I have tried this, and cant seem to find a way to get it working

```
// Verify task status
    CompletableFuture<AuditResult> checkOneFuture =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dummyService.fetchSystemState(var1, var2),
                         executorService);

    CompletableFuture<AuditResult> checkTwoFuture =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dummyService.fetchSystemState(var1, var3),
                         executorService);

    CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> cleanUpFuture =
        checkOneFuture.thenCombineAsync(checkTwoFuture, (check1, check2) -> {
          if (check1.getSuccess() && check2.getSuccess()){
            CompletableFuture<Boolean> cleanUpFutuer = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> cleanUp(check1.id), executorService);
            return syncFuture;
          } else {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false);
          }
        }, executorService);

cleanUpFuture.join();
```

The cleanUpFuture is obviously syntactically not correct, and I am trying to figure ways to get this scenario working. Please help

Comment: Compiles fine (after adding `DummyService` and `AuditResult`), what's syntactically incorrect?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting any errors? Also, why are you returning a `CompletableFuture<Boolean>` from the `thenCombineAsync` stage? Why not just return `Boolean`? The `thenCombineAsync` stage is already asynchronous, there doesn't seem to be a reason to run a separate `CompletableFuture` inside this stage—especially since you're using the same `Executor` for everything.

Comment: My bad, the syntax does work. I was trying to avoid wrapping a Completable in another in the case of "cleanUpFuture", as its an anti-pattern. Is there anyway to avoid that ?

Answer (score 2):

As Slaw says in his comment, why not just return `boolean`?

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> cleanUpFuture =
    checkOneFuture.thenCombineAsync(checkTwoFuture, (check1, check2) -> {
        if (check1.getSuccess() && check2.getSuccess()) {
            return cleanUp(check1.id); // will be scheduled due to combineAsync
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, executorService);
```

Note: for a shorter version, you can do

```
(check1, check2) -> check1.getSuccess() && check2.getSuccess() && cleanUp(check1.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this by a `ForkJoinPool`. Subdivizing your call in subtask by calling `fork()` and reassemble the whole with a `join()`

For this you have maybe to implements a `RecursiveTask`

**EDIT : Using `CompletableFuture`**

If your purpose is to run two async processings in parallel and trigger another on completion of the later then `allOf()` is the best method.

Here is an example :

```
public CompletableFuture<String> findSomeValue() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    sleep(1);
    return "Niraj";
    });
}

@Test
public void completableFutureAllof() {      
List<CompletableFuture<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(num -> {
            list.add(findSomeValue());
});

CompletableFuture<Void> allfuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture[list.size()]));//Created All of object       
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> allFutureList = allfuture.thenApply(val -> {
    return list.stream().map(f -> f.join()).collect(Collectors.toList());
});     

CompletableFuture<String> futureHavingAllValues = allFutureList.thenApply(fn -> {
    System.out.println("I am here");
    return fn.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());});
    String concatenateString = futureHavingAllValues.join();        
    assertEquals("NirajNirajNirajNirajNiraj", concatenateString);
}
```

This is example and more explanations are provided in this [article](https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2019/01/27/Write-Clean-asynchronous-code-with-CompletableFuture-Java-8/)

Comment: Yep, that could work. But am trying to stay away from using the shared ForkJoinPool, also was hoping I could do without the boilerplate of fork/join process.